# How can i cutting a dataframe with 2D in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a key error about calling a dataframe.

```
dist1=pd.read_csv(file1,sep="\s+")
dist1.astype(int)
dist1.columns.astype(int)
```

I call `dist1` with no error. I try to call  `dist1[3][4]`  but it gives key error. Why? I couldn't find the solution. For my problem i need to call `dist1[x][y]` for further configuration. Where did it go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including example input, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). For Pandas-specific tips, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Specifically, we need to see what indexes `dist1` has and what index is erroring. For example, maybe it doesn't have at least 4 columns and 5 rows.

Comment: I solve the problem,i convert the dataframe to numpy array.

Comment: Your question is too generic. As wjandrea said, we need more information, for example: how many columns, rows and leaves does your CSV file have and what kind of data are we talking about in each dataset? What exactly do you expect to access in dist1[3][4] ? Assuming you have a CSV file with only one sheet, which has N rows and M columns, I believe you want to access row 3 from column 4, am I right? If yes, you can try using `dist1.iloc[3][4]`

Comment: Thank all of you for your contribution.I don't want to work with iloc because of mix integer programming

Comment: You're right. It doesn't work with python-mip. However, you need to include the python-mib tag in the topic, to broaden the range of contributions on the topic. This can help people in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I solve the problem by converting the dataframe to numpy

```
dist1=dist1.to_numpy()
```

Comment: This makes it sound like you were trying to use numbered indexes on a labeled index. Why not just use `.iloc`?

Comment: It doesn't work with python-mip.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best answer to your question. It might have resolved. But here you just converted your pandas dataframe structure to a numpy array and overridden your `dist1` variable.

Comment: @özgür Please edit the question to mention that. In the future, please avoid answering unclear questions, including your own.